# Сравнивание 2х массивов из 10 000 000

Tags: php, алгоритм

пишу на php, и есть реальная задача сравнения 2х огромных массивов данных. Но загвостка в том, что эти массивы разбиты по файлам...

файл а1 - содержит 5000 цифр
файл а2 - содержит 5000 цифр
....
И таких файлов очень много
Все вместе это массив более 10 000 000 цифр

Так же есть аналогичные файлы б1, б2, б3... С такой же структурой по 5000 цифр, и по сути это тот же массив что и в а1, только какие-то цифры были удалены от туда, а какие то добавлены.

Так вот мне нужно сравнить эти 2 массива, чтобы на выходе получить что туда добавили а что удалили.

Почему я не могу просто собрать 2 массива из 10 000 000 записей и сравнить их array_diff ??
Да потому что по памяти не вывезу, да и записей может быть в теории куда больше.

По этому ищу решения какого нибудь рекурсивного сравнивания

Comment: Каковы значения в файлах, целые или дробные. Какой разброс значений, минимум, максимум. Есть ли повторы чисел среди одного набора файлов. Требуется ли в случае повторов при сравнении учитывать количество таких повторов в одном и в другом наборе. Близко ли распределение значений в одном наборе к нормальному. Есть ли какой либо порядок значений в файлах / между файлами

Comment: Повторений нет. Ограничений по разбросу нет. Сортировка не известна

Comment: Это я к тому, что для эффективного сравнения их надо отсортировать. Если бы распределение было бы боле менее близко к нормальному, можно было бы пойти путем переразбития входных данных по файлам, в каждом из которых будет определенный набор значений. такие файлы потом элементарно сортируются.

Comment: Если распределение может быть очень далеко от нормального то в каких то файлах может оказаться слишком много значений и они не влезут в память. Тогда придется подходить с другой стороны, читать файлы набора примерно до 2/5 доступной ОЗУ, сортировать и сбрасывать на диск, потом читать и выполнять сортировку слиянием. Что довольно муторно.

Comment: Задача получить отсортированные оба набора в файлах на диске. После этого читая их небольшими кусками можно спокойно сравнивать идя параллельно по ним (как при сортировке слиянием).

Answer (score 0):

В1:Берете А1 и В1. Одинаковые элементы удалили. К А1 добавили А2, к В1 добавили В2, сравнили, снова одинаковые удалили, и т.д.

В2 (более быстрый):

1. Берете А1 и В1. Одинаковые элементы удалили.
2. Берете А2 и В2. Одинаковые элементы удалили.
3. Сравнили остатки А с В2 и наоборот А2 с В.  Одинаковые элементы удалили. (этот пункт делать, если записи могли перемещатся между файлами)
4. Добавили А2 к остаткам А, В2 к остаткам В.
5. пп 2-3 в цикле для остальных...

В результате в массиве А останутся те, которые были удалены, а в массиве В, те которые были добавлены.

Для случая, если файлы могут сильно различатся, можно использовать дополнительные алгоритмы выбора очередного файла для сравнения. Например изначально перебрать все файлы и найти медиану чисел в каждом файле. Отсортировать их в порядке увеличения. И в этом порядке их сравнивать. Возможно также учитывать при выборе файлов минимальное и максимальное число в файле.

Comment: А что если результирующие массивы в память не влезают ? или просто самый худший случай, в файлах A значения все по возрастанию, в B по убыванию. При их последовательном сравнении в остатки будут занесены целиком A и B и только после того как прошли половину файлов начнут от туда понемногу удаляться. В итоге это равнозначно загрузки в память целиком одного из массивов

Comment: насколько я понял из задания, то таких сильных манипуляций там не было.  Вообще здесь нужно понимать цель - если задача ради универсального алгоритма, то это одно. А если есть старые файлы, и новые их варианты (с небольшими изменениями) и нужно сравнить, то это другое... В любом случае количество необходимой памяти уменьшили минимум в два раза..